# bootstrap-vue 2 b-table slots stopped working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using the b-table component and I have 3 columns that I want to customize using slots.

The following code worked for me a in the past but recently it stopped working although nothing regarding the code, component, package versions changed.

```
<b-table
            class="tableWidth"
            sticky-header
            striped
            hover
            :items="tableData"
            :fields="tableColumns"
        >
            <template v-slot:cell(certificationType)="row">
                <b-form-group :style="{ width: '80%' }">
                    <b-form-select
                        plain
                        v-model="row.item.certificationType"
                        :options="certificationTypes"
                    ></b-form-select>
                </b-form-group>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:cell(studentRank)="row">
                <b-form-group :style="{ width: '80%' }">
                    <b-form-select plain v-model="row.item.studentRank" :options="Ranks"></b-form-select>
                </b-form-group>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:cell(selected)="row">
                <b-form-checkbox
                    v-model="row.item.selected"
                    name="checkbox-1"
                    :value="true"
                    :unchecked-value="false"
                />
            </template>
        </b-table>
```

The error the console prints:

> Property or method "row" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

and

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined"

Any ideas what could have happened?

Comment: I suspect this might be because you're using a version of Vue lower than `2.6.0`, as that was the version which introduced `v-slot`. Could you add which version of Vue you have installed to your question?

Comment: @Hiws thanks so much! after updating vue the problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments on the question, the problem was to do with the version of `Vue` being used.

The `v-slot` syntax was introduced in the `2.6.0` release of `Vue`, meaning if you are using a lower version the errors above will appear. As it doesn't know the `row` variable is coming from the slot, but instead thinks it should be available in the component instance.

Updating to `2.6.0` or later should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way, and you can model your `b-table` items to your `b-form-select` or any other inputs. As you can see in the snippet, you can change the select options and see that `tableData` will change.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableColumns: ['first_name_value', 'last_name', ],
      tableData: [{
          isActive: false,
          first_name_value: 'O2',
          last_name: 'Wilson'
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          first_name_value: 'O1',
          last_name: 'Carney'
        }
      ],
      certificationTypes: [{
          text: "option 1",
          value: "O1"
        },
        {
          text: "option 2",
          value: "O2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  {{tableData}}
  <b-table class="tableWidth" sticky-header striped hover :items="tableData" :fields="tableColumns">
    <template v-slot:cell(first_name_value)="{ item }">
                <b-form-group :style="{ width: '80%' }">
                    <b-form-select
                        plain
                        v-model="item.first_name_value"
                        :options="certificationTypes"
                    ></b-form-select>
                </b-form-group>
            </template>
    <template v-slot:cell(studentRank)="row">
                <b-form-group :style="{ width: '80%' }">
                    <b-form-select plain v-model="row.item.studentRank" :options="Ranks"></b-form-select>
                </b-form-group>
            </template>
    <template v-slot:cell(selected)="row">
                <b-form-checkbox
                    v-model="row.item.selected"
                    name="checkbox-1"
                    :value="true"
                    :unchecked-value="false"
                />
            </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```